# What is this manga with Naruto, Luffy, Goku and Ichigo as characters?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I recently found this on the internet they say its gonna replace naruto since naruto shippuden ended , Can any one tell me the name is this boy or anime title ?

[image]

Comment: It looks like Dojinshin since i have seen cross over images of Goku, Naruto, Luffy and Ichigo. that said i very much doubt this will replace Naruto since i dare say it infringes of other Intellectual Properties

Comment: are you asking about the boy with Naruto on the first four panel or the whole page?

Answer (score 5):

He's [Midoriya Izuku](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Izuku_Midoriya) from new manga [Boku no Hero Academia](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=112459)

[image: Boku no Hero Academia poster]

The beginning of the story is kinda like Naruto but set in the modern day school with bunch of people with special powers, but this boy has no special power.